# Union mount doesn't work on macOS Mojave

Tags: mojave, mount

Is union mounting still available on macOS Mojave 10.14.5. I have tried:

- https://aplawrence.com/foo-mac/union-mounts.html

and using `mount -t hfs -o union` with two HFS+ images, and I can't seem to get the files in the lower mount to show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It' sometimes claimed that it is 'sort of' still there, and can be used, mostly untested and wobbly/semi-reliably with proper unix tools, like (gnu)ls from coreutils, but it will not be of much use if one wants to then use Finder with it.

This was answered here:

> Union mounts
> are a very powerful feature that solves many needs, but, sadly, it's not
> something you can rely on for critical-mission projects, because it seems
> to be very little tested, if at all.

> Yea. Short answer: DON'T.
>
> Long answer: Mac OS does not support union mounts. They're there, they are
> honored by posix programs, but everything that using the apple file system
> interface bypasses it.
>
> Which means that just about anything based on cocoa framekworks ... optimizes
> and bypasses union mount visibility.
>
> I ran into  this back on 10.7, and complained, only to get basically this back from apple support engineers.
>
> — [Re: Experiences with union mounts in MacOS?](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=macports-users@lists.macports.org&q=subject:%22Re%5C%3A%20Experiences%20with%20union%20mounts%20in%20MacOS%5C%3F%22&o=newest&f=1)

Also of interest: [What happened to Union Mounts? Another silently deprecated feature?](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/erpg29/what_happened_to_union_mounts_another_silently/)